# Parsing data deeply

Tags: logstash

I have data that I want to parse. I have splitted some part of my data but I need to parse it again. Is there any other way to parse my data?

In my data there is page_size part, I want to put this data another field which I will create. It must be like this : my_newfield_page_size: 25
Same goes to page part. I need it like this: my_newfield_page=1
Last example, I have contains part, I need this "contain" part like this: my_data_type: contains

This is my data:

```
IP Adress - - [01/Jul/2019:13:03:07 +0300] "POST /search?page=1&page_size=25 HTTP/1.1" 200 846 "https://try.com/search/?contains=kingcbd" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170" "IP Adress" "US"
```

This is what I have tried in logstash config file :

```
filter {


   if[method]=="POST"
{
mutate { split => { url => "&" } }

mutate { 



        add_field => {
                "query" => "%{[url][0]}"
        "size" => "%{[url][1]}"
        }



}
mutate { split => {query => "=" } }
mutate { 



        add_field => {

        "amount" => "%{[query][1]}"
        }



}



mutate { split => { referrer => "=" } }
mutate {



        add_field => {
                "query_type" => "%{[referrer][0]}"
                "keyword" => "%{[referrer][1]}"
        }



}

}
  mutate {
    convert => {
      "amount" => "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to ask especially is that is there any other way to parse my data with split method? Is  filtering with split method efficient?

Comment: Pardon me sir. Edited.

Comment: Just a tip: you might want to fix the indentation on that code

Comment: This works well with some data I have specified. But do I have to split all the data when I want to parse. Any other way than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the last part of your question: "What I want to ask especially is that is there any other way to parse my data with split method?"

You can use a grok filter

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

You can check the different patterns supported by Grok here:

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns

It looks like maybe you can use the COMMONAPACHELOG one and then apply another Grok filter on just the data that you need.

Comment: Can grok filter handle with this kind of data:" search/?query=trying" and you want to reach "trying" value from here?

Comment: You can check out this link  http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/  , it has online Grok debugger where you can try your patterns.    

With your input, ```search/?query=trying``` this Grok pattern matches  ```%{WORD:method}\/\?%{WORD:parameter}\=%{WORD:paramValue}``` and you get the value in the "paramValue" field.